# How to get the string data which is outside of parenthesis in C#

Tags: c#

I need to get the data which is outside of parenthesis

```
string data = "English(Language)";

string result= "English";
```

The result should display the text "English".

I tried with Regex but not able to get the desired result.

Comment: Please share what exactly you've tried and what went wrong. What regex did you try? What result did it give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution that I can think of:

```
string data = "English(Language)";
string result = data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf('('));
```

That is of course, if you never need the data within the parenthesis.

---

Another way to do it is by using `String.Split`:

```
string data = "English(Language)";
string result = data.Split('(')[0];
```

This is marginally slower than the first example since it needs to allocate memory for an array.

---

The third way to do it is via regular-expressions:

```
string data = "English(Language)";
var pattern = new Regex("(\\w+\\s?)\\((\\w+)\\)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

string result = pattern.Match(data).Groups[1].Value;
```

This is the slowest of all the examples, but captures both "English" and "Language". It also allows for whitespace `\s?` between *English* and *(Language)*.

A great tool for testing regular expressions is [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/), just remember to escape everything when you move it over to C#.

---

[Here is a fiddle, testing the performance of all options.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bQsriy)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
string input = "English(Language)";
string regex = "(\\(.*\\))";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, regex, "");
```

You will need that:
`using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Answer (score 1):

If you dont bother to use Regex, the below solution works fine.

```
string data = "English(Language)";
string result = Regex.Match(data, @"(.*)\(.*\)").Groups[1].Value;

Console.WriteLine(result); // English
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi take a look at the [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) methods:

```
string data = "English(Language)";

string result= "English";

var value = data.Split('(').First();
Console.WriteLine (value);
```

Result :

```
English
```

Answer (score 0):

xd or just:

```
string data = "English(Language)";
string result = data.Replace("(Language)", "");
```